# Using File.OpenBinary() fails for file. StoragePoint externalization problem?

Tags: sharepoint-server, rbs

I'm trying to restore a file from a backup content database in SharePoint 2016 by using the `Get-SPContentDatabase -ConnectAsUnattachedDatabase` and drilling down to the item level to use the `OpenBinary()` call.

I believe this is failing because the BLOB is externalized via StoragePoint, but I'm not sure how to allow this command to access the external BLOB data. Any ideas on what permissions might be necessary?

The BLOB and endpoint still exist in SharePoint and on the file share and I am successfully able to see the item and its properties within PowerShell.

I found a similar issue where the OP said they solved it by giving explicit permissions to the StoragePoint databases, but I'm not sure what permissions or which databases need them.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645272/listitem-file-openbinary-not-working-remote-blob-storage-filestreaming-no/6694760

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. The particular server I was testing from didn't have the full StoragePoint installation on it, only a portion. Running the same call from one of the WFEs I was able to download the file successfully.